# Combined two mod rewrite htaccess rules into one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I combined these 2 htaccess mod_rewrite rules into one using `OR`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%20(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%2B(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Is this how?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%20(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%2B(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

or is there even a shorter way than that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How is your original URL looking?

Comment: just wanting to slim down code. The original URL is fine. Still need to figure out how to redirect old query to new query with the extra parameter in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex alternation:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?:%20|%2B|\s)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: How would I go about adding onto this one `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position)[^=]+=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?position=%1 [L,R=301]` adding into it !occupation

Comment: is this correct? `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:!position)[^=]+=|(!occupation|\s)[^=]+=(.*)$`

Comment: Keep this position rule before my suggested rule.

Comment: I don't think I did it right. How would I add to this condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position)[^=]+=(.*)$` to include `?!occupation`?

Comment: There was no reference of position and occupation in your question so I am unable to understand the ask here. Can you clarify your requirement a little more.

Comment: sure. I just want to add on to another RewriteCond I have in my htaccess file. I thought I could follow your example above to `|` it but I can't get it right. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position)[^=]+=(.*)$` is the other Cond I'm trying to addon to it. Do you see where it says `(?!position)`? So if is not position is what it says. I need to also include if is not occupation. So I'm trying to add onto it to also says `(?!occupation)`.

The entire cond and rule is
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position)[^=]+=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?position=%1 [L,R=301]`